# How to Convert ELF to Raw Binary

Tags: c#, elf, bin

I need to convert an ELF file to the raw `bin` file.

I've had a look at Elf sharp but I need the code not the lib and I did not get it to work.

```cs
if (data[1] == 'E' && data[2] == 'L' && data[3] == 'F')
 {
   // get binary from elf
 }
```

To conclude, I need code that can extract the raw binary from an ELF file.

Comment: Binary should by a byte[].   Character are 2 bytes in c# and you must convert to one byte.  Try following :            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("filename");

            if (data[1] == (byte)'E' && data[2] == (byte)'L' && data[3] == (byte)'F')

Comment: Take a look at `objcopy`. Depending on what you really want `objcopy  -O binary input output` may or may not do what you want.